# How can I correctly output a dataframe with the values(?) of a JSON as columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

First time posting.I am Learning how to use Python and decided I will do so using the Riot Games API.
Anyway, I'm trying to output a Legends of Runeterra leaderboard into a DataFrame, however my DataFrame is not mapping 'correctly'. I've done a lot of Googling and have finally given up and thought I'd just ask.
Im betting it's something obvious!

This is my current query - Nice a simple...(This took me 2 hours :P)

```py
import requests
import pandas

response = requests.get("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lor/ranked/v1/leaderboards?api_key=RGAPI-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx")
response_file = response.json()
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(response_file,orient='columns')
print(data)
```

It outputs:

[image: Output]

I dont want the 'players' key to be the column. I want the **Name**, **Rank** and **LP** to be the columns. I believe these are called values? But I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Any help, or links to posts that I have missed that help resolve this would be amazing.
Thank you

**EDIT 13:20 13/02/2021**
Attached JSON file as requested

https://pastebin.com/ks4AaXQp
I couldnt figure out how to attach a file here, so I threw it in PasteBin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_json(response_file)
```

If this does not work, post the response_file as a .json file and I'll try to assist you further.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back so quickly. It didn't work unfortunately.
It output an error: 

```ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>```

 I couldnt figure out how to upload the JSON so I threw it in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/ks4AaXQp

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this myself.

I didn't specify the 'Key' when creating the DataFrame:

The corrected Code is:

```
import requests
import pandas

response = requests.get("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lor/ranked/v1/leaderboards?api_key=RGAPI-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx")
response_file = response.json()
data = pandas.DataFrame(response_file['players'])
print(data)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCWqL.png)